# Sound half as loud in Render as in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I have been editing some videos in the Blender 3.0 VSE. I'm running this on Linux Mint. The sound comes from MP3 audio strips which sound perfect when played through the VSE. However, when rendered, the sound in the video is about half as loud as it plays in the VSE. All the volume settings I can find are set to 1.000.

Does anyone have any idea what would cause this discrepancy? In my mind, the VSE sound volume and the rendered video file sound volume should be identical.
Thanks

Comment: I rendered the project in Blender 2.8. Same problem.
Next I rendered the same video and music tracks in Shotcut video editor. Same problem.
Conclusion - the problem is with Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon not Blender. If someone knows where I can adjust the sound so the rendered sound levels are louder, please let me know. For me this is a real head scratcher.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I assumed because the volume control on my headphones changed the volume, it was the correct volume. However, my media player also has a volume control which was turned down low. Turning up the media player volume fixed the problem. To test the render, I should have played the render in the VSE.